# how to check if Color exists in asset catalog

Tags: xcode, swiftui, xcasset

I want to take a string and see if there's a matching color in my bundles asset catalog. If it exists the set a variable to that color and if not set to another.

e.g

```
let matchedColor = Color(string) ?? Color.red
```

however as Color(string) is not an optional I can't use nil coalescing operator.

Comment: SwiftUI Color is a _view_, not a color. You will get a view no matter what. If you are going to use a string _variable_ to refer to the color set in your asset catalog, then you're just asking for trouble. Set up a system of static properties or enum cases so that accidentally referring to a nonexistent color set is impossible.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
Color(uiColor: UIColor(named: "MyColor") ?? UIColor.blue)
```

Which is a short for:

```
if let color = UIColor(named: "MyColor") {
    Color(uiColor: color)
} else {
    /// Your other color here
    Color.blue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach using `UIImage` to check if the named asset
is in the `Assets` folder:

```
 func isInAssets(_ name: String) -> Bool {
     UIImage(named: name) != nil ? true : false
 }
```